# Gridview disable edit on 1 column asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview, edit

I am using a gridview Edit to edit the values i have in my gridview, when i press edit, all columns can be edited, i would like that one of the columns is not allowed to be edited.

Is there any way i can do this?

Thiss is my aspx code:

```
<asp:GridView 

ID="GridView1" 
runat="server" 
AllowSorting="True" 
OnRowCommand="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1" 
AutoGenerateEditButton="True" 
OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" 
CellSpacing="10"
OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" ShowFooter="True" 
onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"
OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing">



</asp:GridView>
```

Thanks

Comment: how are you binding your gridview. TemplateField or BoundField?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, make use of the EditItemTemplate. In the following example field ID will not be edited in the Edit mode:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server">
    <Columns>
        ...
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("ID") %>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        ...
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: this works, but it creates another column and does not make the current one read only

Comment: That's because by default GridView's property `AutoGenerateColumns` is set to true. So it generates columns for every property of the object that is provided as a DataItem and adds the declared column (ID in our case). There is no way you can affect the behavior of auto generated columns. If you want something custom (like edit disabling on a certain column) you should switch off auto generation of columns and declare everything you need using BoundField, TemplateField etc.

Answer (score 28):

If you are using `asp:BoundField`, try

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID"
        ReadOnly="true"      
        HeaderText="Customer ID"/>
```

Or else if you are using `asp:TemplateField`, you can either

1. Render it in either an `asp:Label` inside `EditItemTemplate`
2. *Omit* the `EditItemTemplate` for that column altogether

Comment: i am using databind, im trying to use your boundfield but its telling me that its not found

Comment: see this example. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.aspx BoundField must be inside `Columns`

Comment: This is the best solution if you are using boundfields. And if possible, put the non editable fields in the BoundField.

Answer (score 0):

please show some markup. Quick and dirty I think depending on your markup aspx you can remove the textbox from the EditItem template for the column you want to prevent editing... there are also other solutions of course :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using template field

```
((TemplateField)gvGridView.Columns[index]).EditItemTemplate = null;
```

if boundfield

```
((BoundField)gvGridView.Columns[index]).ReadOnly = true;
```